# Update transmission

Tags: raspbmc

Currently I am using the latest version of RASPBMC and I have installed transmission from stable repositories.
Sadly, I figured that the "stable" package is the 2.52-3, but the development has moved forward until version 2.77. I'd wish to install the latest version, since I have some troubles and I'd wish to check if it has been fixed in later releases, so I followed this tutorial:
http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/forum/t-374712/how-to:install-latest-transmission-from-debian

However, when it comes to update the underalying library, it seems that something is missing for the ARM architecture, so everything fails.
Long story short, did anyone successfully update transmission in his Pi?

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but why don't you try rtorrent+rutorrent? Lightweight and much more options than Transmission :)

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? Arne's answer is basically your best option for experimental software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved with Apt-Pinning.

In that way you can choose to use jessie's repository to obtain an update (!not the latest!) version of transmission, actually is 2.82-1.1.

Here how you can do it:

sudo apt-cache show transmission-daemon | grep Version
Will show you only one version (the wheezy's version), right?

### Add jessie repository to /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie  main contrib non-free

deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free

### Create/edit /etc/apt/preferences.d/jessie.pref

Package: *

Pin: release n=jessie

Pin-Priority: 50

### Update APT

sudo apt-get update

### Check if configuration is OK

First check:

sudo apt-cache show transmission-daemon

OK - if show two versions

Second check:

sudo apt-cache policy transmission-daemon

OK - if the version table show two records and the candidate is the **oldest** because we don't want to use jessie's repository for "normal" apt jobs.

### Install Transmission from jessie repository

Now we can force aptget to use jessie's repository:

sudo apt-get install **-t jessie** transmission-daemon

Let me know if this work for you.

p.s. Some infos source from raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48672&p=379680

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.77 has only been in experimental so far, I would guess that it will take some time to arrive in wheezy. The tutorial you link to will most probably not work, since standard Debian repositories will not work for the Pi. You might have more luck building transmission from source, although I am not sure if you can do that on the Pi. You might need to do some [cross compiling](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426). There seem to be instructions on how to re-build [Debian packages for the Pi](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/06/17/using-debian-multiarch-for-cross-compiling) as well.