# Update Transmission to 2.94

Tags: raspbian-stretch, apt, update

I have found an answer given in 2014, [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/update-transmission), which suggests a method for updating the Transmission version available on the Raspberry Pi's default repositories to the latest version. This appears to be out of date advice and no longer works for latest (as of 05-May-2019) Transmission version, 2.94.

How do I go about installing Transmission 2.94 on my Raspberry Pi today? I have Raspbian-Stretch installed.